# Looking to add a dynamically adding rows table with multiple fixed columns which can fill value's to Google form and bring response to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I'm trying to create a table with editable cells in a google form that lets people enter their response. It would have multiple fixed columns and dynamically adding rows for more response.

[Sample image of the desired table in google form for response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nNJ.png)

I am naive about building google forms and running scripts/codes on forms. A detailed explanation of steps will be of good help.

Thanking in advance to wonderful people who do such fabulous work

Comment: Pretty sure google forms isn't designed to to that: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25641142?hl=en . Describe your goal. Maybe something like a shared Google Sheets worksheet would meet your goal. Or maybe there is a way to use the available form entry options to meet your goal.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to insert tables in Google Forms, not even via Apps Script, but since you are interested in learning about Forms and Scripts I would recommend you start with [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) about managing Form responses.

If you explain perhaps with more detail what your goal by inserting the table is, maybe there is a way with the available options in forms to achieve it.